# Azure - Send Google Push Notifications without Azure Mobile Services

Tags: android, azure, asp.net-web-api, push-notification

As the title says, is it possible to send push notifications to Google Play Store without the help of Azure Mobile Services?

Currently, I have an Azure VM and I have built my own custom implementations for sending messages to Google Play Store for push notifications. But I'm having trouble in getting the push notifications sent properly.

I can send the push notifications just fine using a non-Azure server though. Are there any specific configurations that I have to prepare to enable Azure VM to properly send push notifications?

I'm using Microsoft's WebAPI and publish the server project directly from Visual Studio using the Publish Wizard.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the calls to the Google Push API to see if calls are being blocked because they originate in Azure?  If so, what error messages are you seeing? A bit hard to diagnose without.

Answer (score 0):

The expired push token is the culprit.